# VueJs подсчет количества товаров в корзине

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

Создаю интернет-магазин на nuxt js. Есть корзина в которую мы добавляем товар. Добавление с помощью кнопки "+" и убавление с помощью "-" работает, но также необходимо чтобы была возможность ввести количество вручную в инпут в котором выводится значение. Как это можно реализовать? Как связать данные введенные пользователем в инпут с данными где подсчитывается количество?

```
 <input
      v-model="inputValue"
      class="quantity-value text-right"
      type="number"
      name="inputQuantity"
      :placeholder="cart_item_data.quantity"
      >
```

На данный момент значение количества подсчитывается с помощью мутации в store, в документации сказано что с инпутом нужно использовать v-model, но как передать значение v-model в action для того чтобы потом в мутации присвоить cart_item_data.quantity введенное пользователем значение?

Answer (score 0):

У тебя обработчики кликов по кнопкам выполняют некоторый код. Аналогичный код надо вызвать в событии изменения значения инпута - это `change`, `input` или `blur` в зависимости от момента, в который надо применить введённое значение. У реакта `change` работает как `input`, про vue не в курсе.

Comment: уже решил спасибо))